# Can I handle a particular jasmine error for protractor tests?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation, overriding

We have some monitoring tests which execute continuously on a schedule and sometime it fails due to unknown network related error.

Fixing the random network error is priority one but meanwhile I was thinking of handling such error gracefully - either on protractor or jasmine.

The error message is always the same so I was wondering if there is a way I can handle that error through protractor config file or somewhere?

For example:

```
expect(obj1).isEqual(obj2)
```

When there is a real failure jasmine gives error message like

```
obj1 is not equal to obj2
```

When there is random network error which has consistent message then jasmine prints the error looks like

```
Unable to connect to network. It may be busy now so please try later (example message)
```

I want to override all the jasmine errors and only ignore reporting as failure for my example message.

Error tracelog:

```
Stacktrace:
 UnknownError: <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>*** Web Proxy</title>
            <LINK REL ="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="http://xdddd.com/cacheflow/errors.css" TITLE="Style">
            </head>
            <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ccccff">
                    <tr><td><font size="-3"> </font></td></tr> 
                    <tr><td valign="middle">
                            <h2>  <img SRC="http://home.xx.com/art/logos/black_51x51.gif" ALT="XXXXXXXX" border="0" height="51" width="51">   Web Proxy Error - TCP Error 503</h2> <hr size="1" color="black"> </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <font color=red><b>XXXXXXXXX.com</b></font><p>
            The Firm's web proxy could not contact the web server in the URL above.  This can happen when the web
            server is down, too busy, or is unreachable on the Internet.  Try the server again later. If you receive
            this message for many URLs, please contact your local helpdesk to report the problem.
            <font size="-1"><br><br><br>
            Reporting proxy: uxxxxxx.com<br><br>
             Copyright 2000 - The XXXXXXXX, Inc. - All rights reserved.
            </font>
            </body>
            </html>

    at new bot.Error (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (h:\Projects\mdddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:11)
    at h:\Projects\xxxxxxx\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:379:20
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:1857:20)
    at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:2448:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\dddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:564:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:553:15)
    at [object Object].goog.async.run.processWorkQueue [as _onTimeout] (h:\Projects\ddddddn\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:392:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:721:11)
    at [object Object].expectHomePage (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\test-common\page-objects\learning-center.js:10:20)
    at h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:1857:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:1729:8)
    at [object Object].eval (eval at <anonymous> (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1124:19), <anonymous>:2043:12)
    at [object Object].goog.async.run.processWorkQueue [as _onTimeout] (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (h:\Projects\dddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (h:\Projects\dddddddn\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\test-monitoring\specs\learning-center.spec.js:11:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
    at describe (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (h:\Projects\ddddddd\web\private-site\test-monitoring\specs\learning-center.spec.js:5:1)
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete error traceback? Thanks.

Comment: hope that tracelog helps. I hidden some information and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @alecxe for the clue in tracelog. Might be basic but still want to answer and hopefully help to someone.

Since I am using Jasmine 1.3, I found many places to override the failure in minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js but the best place I found to override is below:

```
jasmine.Spec.prototype.fail = function (e) {
  if(e.message && e.message.indexOf('timed out after')>=0) {
    console.log("EXCEPTION MSG " + JSON.stringify(e, null, 4));
    var expectationResult = new jasmine.ExpectationResult({
      passed: true,
      message: 'Skipped for proxy error',
      trace: { stack: e.stack }
    });
  }
  else {
    var expectationResult = new jasmine.ExpectationResult({
      passed: false,
      message: e ? jasmine.util.formatException(e) : 'Exception',
      trace: { stack: e.stack }
    });    
  }
  this.results_.addResult(expectationResult);
};
```